# For loop only displaying last iteration Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a for loop that adds a button to every link on the page. However, it's only adding the button to the last link of the array.

```js
// Vars
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".g a");
let dropdownBtn = document.createElement("button");

// Call
CreateBtn();
StyleLinks();

function CreateBtn() {
  dropdownBtn.id = "dropdown-btn";
}

// Style and loop links
function StyleLinks() {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = count; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.color = "red";
    links[i].appendChild(dropdownBtn);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why does a  function called "CreateBtn" not create a button? Note that an id should exist only once on a page.

Comment: haha...I have no idea, but it does now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating **1** button and appending it to the  tags, you need to create a new instance of the button every single time the loop runs.